# How to plot graphs from own function in subplot in Python Pandas Matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have my own created function to plot some graphs like `myFunction(arg1, arg2)`.
My function creates one plot for certain column.
I would like to create my plots (using my fucntion) in matplotlib subplot. I tried to do like below:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
myFunction(arg1, arg2)
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
myFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

But it does not work, I have strange results (simply it does not wor).

My question: could you show me sample code how can I use my function in sublot method? To plot many plots (creating by my function) of one cell in Python JupyterLab?

Comment: Use the object-oriented interface when plotting and pass an Axes to `myFunction`.

Comment: do you have some example ? BigBen ?

Comment: I'd read the [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html), then adjust your plotting code in `myFunction` accordingly, then add an additional parameter `ax`.